# What does it mean for a function to be decidable? (homework)

Tags: terminology, computability

**Note:** This is part of a homework exercise. I am asking for clarifications, not a solution!

**Given:** Assume $g: \mathbb{N} \mapsto \mathbb{N}, g\in R$ ($R$ is the class of recursive functions) is a strictly monotone function, i.e., $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}: g(n)  < g(n+1)$.

Prove that $g(\mathbb{N})$ is decidable.

**Clarification of the assignment:**
I am not sure I understand the exercise correctly. What does it mean that a function is decidable? I assume that it's a decision problem of the form "For $x \in \mathbb{N}$, is $x\in range(g)$? For a function $g$ to be decidable, we can then define a decision procedure that returns $yes$ or $no$ for any $x$.

Is this correct? Or am I on the wrong track?

Comment: Check the definitions!

Comment: @Raphael: I did. "Decidable" is used intuitively, but not defined formally in the script.

Comment: What about the referenced textbooks? (There's really little use for us to reproduce standard definitions here...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not asking to prove that the function $g$ is decidable, but the *image* $g(\mathbb{N})$ is decidable. The image is a subset of $\mathbb{N}$, namely
$$g(\mathbb{N}) = \{ k \in \mathbb{N} \mid \exists n \in \mathbb{N} . g(n) = k \}.$$
The question reduces to showing decidability of "given $k$, does there exist $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $g(n) = k$?".

Comment: Thanks! Seems I was on the right track, just confused because of not applying the terminology correct.

Comment: No, you were confused about correctly understanding the meaning of the expression $g(\mathbb{N})$. You thought it was a function, which it is not. The function is $g$. Actually, this is sloppy notation, we should use something like $g_{*}(S)$ for *image* and $g(S)$ for *value*.

Comment: _Or_ we could just use $\:\operatorname{Range}(\hspace{.02 in}g\hspace{-0.02 in})\;$. $\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer: that would work for the entire range, but you still need something for the image of a subset of the domain, i.e., if $f : X \to Y$ and $S \subseteq X$, we need something like $f_*(S)$.